# Simple lambda expressions C++03 without boost and so on

Tags: c++, lambda, c++03

Could you, please, give an idea how to implement basic lambda expressions in C++03 without special libraries, in a simple, elegant and smart way? They should make it possible to do something like this:

```
for_each(some_vector.begin(), some_vector.end(), _first = -5)
sort(some_vector.begin(), some_vector.end(), _first > _last)
```

I have seen many topics on StackOverflow and in other places in the Internet, but, unfortunately, I didn't find something useful. Another idea is to look into Boost implementation carefully, but, sadly, my level is not very appropriate for it now.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: NO BOOST. But you can download it, and see its implementation. I think, it has elegant and smart implementation. If you cannot understand boost, then you cannot understand other implementation as well.

Comment: @Nawaz, op claims his ability is not at that level yet (heck, I look at the code sometimes and go wtf?)

Comment: Using boost would be ideal otherwise upgrade your compiler and use the standard lambdas. Reinventing the wheel is not something that even experienced programmers do often.

Comment: If you can't understand the code in boost, what makes you think you would understand our code?  Increase your level.

Comment: @Nim: Yeah, I read that. So I edited my comment accordingly.

Comment: I don't think the Boost code is necessarily a good introduction to TMP. It is full of work-arounds for broken compilers and helper macros. Starting with something clean related to the topic seems easier. Arriving at a robust, portable solution is probably not the aim of the OP either.

Comment: Actually, I've implemented a simple version of Boost.Phoenix. I did this just out of fun and to feed my curiosity, but if I post that here, I've to explain it as well which scares the hell out of me, for it has lots of metaprogramming.

Comment: @Nawaz Commenting it thoroughly or making it into a small tutorial would be awesome, but also very time consuming. I'd certainly like to see it.

Comment: @pmr: If you want to see it, I can post it (after making it a bit short) but I wouldn't explain it probably; I don't have that much patience.

Comment: @Nawaz Sure, post it as an answer or edit it into mine as another example implementation.

Comment: Thank you! I think that pmr has pointed a good idea, and it was a one reason why I didn't want to read boost code carefully, because there are sometimes some not very simple constructions that were created for different compilers. I hope I was able to realize something like boost.lambda with the help of you and people in another topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501991/deduction-template-argument-c Thank you again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, the most common implementation technique for lambdas are [expression templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates).

[This article](http://www10.informatik.uni-erlangen.de/~pflaum/pflaum/ProSeminar/exprtmpl.html) gives an excellent introduction but you should really get one of the books on C++ TMP to get some further insight.