# Deduction template argument C++

Tags: c++, templates

Please, consider the code below:

```
template<typename T>
bool function1(T some_var) { return true; }

template <typename T>
bool (*function2())(T) {
  return function1<T>;
}

void function3( bool(*input_function)(char) ) {}
```

If I call

```
function3(function2<char>());
```

it is ok. But if I call

```
function3(function2());
```

compiler gives the error that it is not able to deduction the argument for template.

Could you, please, advise (give an idea) how to rewrite function1 and/or function2 (may be, fundamentally to rewrite using classes) to make it ok?

*** Added ***

I am trying to do something simple like lambda expressions in Boost.LambdaLib (may be, I am on a wrong way):

```
sort(some_vector.begin(), some_vector.end(), _1 < _2)
```

I did this:

```
template<typename T>
bool my_func_greater (const T& a, const T& b) {
  return a > b;
}

template<typename T>
bool my_func_lesser (const T& a, const T& b) {
  return b > a;
}

class my_comparing {
 public:
  int value;
  my_comparing(int value) : value(value) {}
  template <typename T>
  bool (*operator<(const my_comparing& another) const)(const T&, const T&) {
    if (this->value == 1 && another.value == 2) {
      return my_func_greater<T>;
    } else {
      return my_func_greater<T>;
    }
  }
};

const my_comparing& m_1 = my_comparing(1);
const my_comparing& m_2 = my_comparing(2);
```

It works:

```
sort(a, a + 5, m_1.operator< <int>(m_2));
```

But I want that it doesn't require template argument as in LambdaLib.

Comment: Classes won't help here, as template parameter deduction does not work for them. Your problem essentially boils down to inferring the parameter-type based on the return-type, which is not possible.

Comment: What's wrong with `function3(function2<char>());`?

Comment: Can you change `function3` or is that carved in stone?

Comment: Could you explain the definition of `function2`? I thought I was a competent C++ programmer, but I'm completely unable to parse that.

Comment: @jalf: That's a function that returns a pointer to a function that gets a `T` and returns a `bool`. I think it's a sign that you are indeed a good C++ programmer if you cannot parse that immediately (I had to go back to the depths of C-days to figure it out).

Comment: Oh right. Yeah, I see it now. Thanks :)

Comment: @jalf: the problem stems from not being able to specify a typedef with template arguments :x I think C++11 would allow [such syntax](http://ideone.com/fr0l9): `template <typename T> using F = bool (*)(T)` and thus `template <typename T> F<T> function2() { return function1<T>; }`

Comment: @MatthieuM.: in C++11 the declaration could also be clarified using a trailing return type (and/or `decltype`)

Comment: @jalf: ah, good thinking! I keep forgetting about `decltype` and `declval` :x

Comment: Deduction only considers function parameters. Since function2 does not get any parameters, there can't be any deduction.

Comment: Ad added: You should be using functors and `std::function` instead of function pointers like Boost.Lambda does. See answer below for details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deduction from return type is not possible. So `function2` can't be deduced from what return type you expect.

It is however possible to deduce cast operator. <strike>So you can replace `function2` with a helper structure like:</strike> Unfortunately there is no standard syntax for declaring cast operator to function pointer without typedef and type deduction won't work through typedef. Following definition works in some compilers (works in G++ 4.5, does not work in VC++ 9):

```
struct function2 {
    template <typename T>
    (*operator bool())(T) {
        return function1<T>;
    }
};
```

(see also [C++ Conversion operator for converting to function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755673/c-conversion-operator-for-converting-to-function-pointer)).

The call should than still look the same.

Note: C++11 introduces alternative typedef syntax which can be templated. It would be like:

```
struct function2 {
    template <typename T>
    using ftype = bool(*)(T);

    template <typename T>
    operator ftype<T>() {
        return function1<T>;
    }
};
```

but I have neither G++ 4.7 nor VC++ 10 at hand, so I can't test whether it actually works.

---

**Ad Added:**

The trick in Boost.Lambda is that it does not return functions, but functors. And functors can be class templates. So you'd have:

```
template<typename T>
bool function1(T some_var) { return true; }

class function2 {
    template <typename T>
    bool operator()(T t) {
        function1<T>;
    }
};

template <typename F>
void function3( F input_function ) { ... input_function(something) ... }
```

Now you can write:

```
function3(function2);
```

and it's going to resolve the template inside `function3`. All STL takes functors as templates, so that's going to work with all STL.

However if don't want to have `function3` as a template, there is still a way. Unlike function pointer, the `std::function` (C++11 only, use `boost::function` for older compilers) template can be constructed from any functor (which includes plain function pointers). So given the above, you can write:

```
void function3(std::function<bool ()(char)> input_function) { ... input_function(something) ... }
```

and now you can still call:

```
function3(function2());
```

The point is that `std::function` has a template constructor that internally generates a template wrapper and stores a pointer to it's method, which is than callable without further templates.

Comment: Could you, please, give an idea why this code is not compiled in Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: @Programmer585: Thanks. I fixed the syntax to the point it works correctly in gcc, but it does not seem to be possible in vc++ at all.

Answer (score 5):

Compiler don't use context of expression to deduce its template parameters. For compiler, `function3(function2());` looks as

```
auto tmp = function2();
function3(tmp);
```

And it don't know what `function2` template parameter is.

Comment: That's why we have to specify argument types for lambdas - `[](int x){}`, not `[](x){}`

Answer (score 2):

After your edit, I think what you want to do can be done simpler. See the following type:

```
struct Cmp {
  bool const reverse;
  Cmp(bool reverse) : reverse(reverse) {}
  template <typename T> bool operator()(T a, T b) {
    return reverse != (a < b);
  }
};
```

Now, in your `operator<` you return an **untyped** `Cmp` instance depending on the order of your arguments, i.e. `m_2 < m_1` would return `Cmp(true)` and `m_1 < m_2` would return `Cmp(false)`.

Since there is a templated `operator()` in place, the compiler will deduce the right function inside `sort`, not at your call to `sort`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this help you and I am not an expert on this. I have been watching this post since yesterday and I want to participate in this.

The template cannot deduce it's type because the compiler does not know what type you are expecting to return. Following is a simple example which is similar to your function2().

```
template<typename T>
T foo() {
    T t;
    return t;
};
```

call this function

```
foo(); // no type specified. T cannot be deduced.
```

Is it possible to move the template declaration to the class level as follows:

```
template<typename T>
bool my_func_greater (const T& a, const T& b) {
  return a > b;
}

template<typename T>
bool my_func_lesser (const T& a, const T& b) {
  return b > a;
}

template <typename T>
class my_comparing {
public:
    int value;
    my_comparing(int value) : value(value) {}
    bool (*operator<(const my_comparing& another) const)(const T&, const T&) {
        if (this->value == 1 && another.value == 2) {
            return my_func_greater<T>;
        } else {
            return my_func_greater<T>;
        }
    }
};
```

and declare m_1 and m_2 as below:

```
const my_comparing<int>& m_1 = my_comparing<int>(1);
const my_comparing<int>& m_2 = my_comparing<int>(2);
```

Now you can compare as follows:

```
if( m_1 < m_2 )
    cout << "m_1 is less than m_2" << endl;
else
    cout << "m_1 is greater than m_2" << endl;
```

I know this is simple and everyone knows this. As nobody posted this, I want to give a try.